# sysctl setting not persist on wsl2

Tags: ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl-2

On every windows 10 restart I need to type this command `sudo sysctl -w vm.max_map_count=262144` in the wsl ubuntu env. I want it to be persistent so I will not need to do it on every restart. I tried to edit /etc/sysctl.conf and in a conf file inside /etc/sysctl.d directory.

I am using Windows 10 (1909), Ubuntu and docker on wsl2 (5.4.72-microsoft-standard-WSL2).
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS
Release:        20.04
Codename:       focal

Comment: There is a raised issue in [WSL github](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/4232) and it seems there is no clean solution yet :/